# CoreData Migration new attribute Swift

Tags: database, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a CoreData database in Swift. I added a new version in which i **added 3 more attributes**. The problem is that if a user has already added some values to the database, **before I added the new attributes to the database**, the app will crash. This is due I want to read out the whole database with all its values. But if the user has added some values before I added the new version, then there will be **no values in the new added attributes**. **So I read out the attributes which hold no values**. Can I change it so like all old attributes will automatically be something like an empty string, so it won't crash? Or can I catch the error or something?

Comment: You can set a default value in the model, or deal with the possibility in code, or create a mapping model

Comment: Made it through a default value in my CoreData model and then IMPORTANT removed the optional tick. Before I didn't removed the optional tick and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write a reader function that throws  and in the error handling call a different function which is for the old inputs . PS, would be easier to help you if you post the code

```
//error type
enum Error: ErrorType{
    case OldInput
}
func fetchFromDatabase() throws {
   //do you fetching 
   if //condition if the new attribute exists {
        //fetch
        return
   }
   throw Error.OldInput
}

//calling it
do {
   try fetchFromDatabase()
} catch (error) {
   fetchFromDatabaseOld()
}
```